# Angular.js and update condition

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements

I have two services that call a restful API returning some json.
I want to update my UI with a message when both calls are done.

FYI, i store the json in 2 differents $scope variables in my controller.

What is the best way and the cleanest way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your promises to variables and then use $q.all to group them into another promise that will resolve when both of them are done.

```
var promise_one = service_one.getItems().then(function(data) {
  $scope.value_one = data;
});

var promise_two = service_two.getItems().then(function(data) {
  $scope.value_two = data;
});

$q.all([promise_one, promise_two]).then(function() {
  alert('Both calls are done!');
});
```